# Django date & time field Picker

Tags: django

I have a "event_venue_DateTime" DateTimeField in my models.py and I want to do a date & time picker for this field.

How do i implement it?

models.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

    from django.db import models

    class calendar_event(models.Model):

        event_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        event_description = models.TextField(max_length=50)

        event_venue_DateTime = models.DateTimeField()

        def __unicode__(self):
            return self.event_name
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from models import calendar_event

#This class is for create to extend the django model framework
class CalendarForm(forms.ModelForm):


    class Meta:
        model = calendar_event
        fields = '__all__'
```

Template.html

```
<html>

<body>


{% block content %}
<h2>Create Events</h2>
<form action="/create/" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
<ul>
{{form.as_ul}}
</ul>

<input type="submit" value="Create" />

</form>

{% endblock %}

</body>

</html>
```

I have searched up and down but havent found a legit date AND time picker. Mostly were just date pickers or datetime pickers that are not used on Django

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you mean but you can implement `jQuery datepicker` like this one: [picker](https://tarruda.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

Then just add appropriate class to your datetime field by overriding the form constructor

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CalendarForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['event_venue_DateTime'].widget.attrs['class'] = 'datetimepicker'
```

and intiate a picker in your `html` template

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
    $('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
  });
</script>
```

Your datetime picker should now be working. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hello. Appreciate your reply. I am an amateur programmer so forgive me if i asked stupid questions.

Comment: I added in the def __init__ method into my forms.py & added in the javascript into my html template. But it still can't seems to work. The field remains as a normal textfield

Comment: did you also include datepicker itself?

Comment: I dont know how to implement jquery datepicker? I downloaded the file and it has a javascript and css file. So do i link it in my html ?

Comment: yes, you have to add that to you html, preferably inside `<head>` tag